# PyQt: How to refer to a dialogue window once it's connected with another window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating a program which has a settings menu in the shape of another window (This used to be a QMainWindow but I read that a QDialog would work better for this so I manually converted the QMainWindow into a QDialog window)

I created the settings menu on its own, and it works perfectly fine on its own, but when I try to integrate it into my main program, the parts of the secondary program which had me manipulating the QDialog itself (eg resizing) result in my program crashing.

Here's the specific part I'm referring to:

```
def preset(self):
    self.op_summer_papers.hide()
    self.op_winter_papers.hide()
    Dialog.resize(302, 450)
```

"Dialog" is the name assigned to the QDialog itself, its even used when calling the second window, as shown below:

```
def settings_panel(self):
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.exec_()
```

Now I used to have two separate .py files, one for the main window and one for the settings dialog, and the settings dialog worked perfectly when run on its own as a seperate entity. But when I used the code above and integrated it into my main program anything that calls "Dialog" results in the program crashing (I've even tried 'Dialog.close()' and that crashes it as well).

I've tried merging the two files into one file, and that didn't work either. I've tried using "self.resize()" instead of "Dialog.resize", also didn't work.

Here's the complete file (edited to include only the relevant bits):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random
import os

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def settings_panel(self):
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.exec_()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(807, 524)

# The setupUI continues here, setting up the main window

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.actionOptions.triggered.connect(self.settings_panel)

# Now this launches the dialog window (works fine here)
# Below is the code for the second program

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(302, 150)

# The "Dialog.resize()" here works as intended

        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.op_custom_radio.toggled.connect(self.custom)
        self.op_preset_radio.toggled.connect(self.preset)

    def custom(self):
        Dialog.resize(302, 450)

    def preset(self):
        Dialog.resize(302, 150)

# The Dialog.resize() here causes the program to crash
```

The "Dialog.resize()" part worked perfectly fine while the application was independent, but it no longer works now that its part of my main application.

Comment: `self.Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()`, etc.

Comment: So what do I do for the parameters of setupUi ?

Comment: Just use `self.Dialog` wherever you were using `Dialog`.

Comment: That's what I did, but it resulted in an invalid syntax error at setupUi(self, self.Dialog)

Comment: Please try to use a little bit of common sense. The `self.Dialog` is only needed within the `Ui_MainWindow` class. It is there so you can access the dialog from other methods within the main window.

Comment: PS: I strongly advise you to read a basic tutorial on how to write pyqt applications (try [this one](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/)). The way you are currently structuring your code is making things unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will be looking into the tutorial as well, I am very new to this and I've been relying far too much on QtDesigner, looks like I should get a hang of the basics first.

Comment: If you're using Qt Designer, you should read [this section](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) in the pyqt docs. The second and third examples shown there are much easier to work with. You should also avoid editing the gui modules created by pyuic. Always import the gui module, and use it as shown in those code examples.